# Inserting a custom HTML field value and get it accessed in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to insert javascript that calculates total prices that need to be stored in the database, but the field is blank in the database after I submit the form. I need the total cost to show on the website and insert into the database.

I tried to put two forms for price. One is to show the javascript. another one is to insert the result into the database. I think I should edit HTML codes to fix this problem, but I don't know-how. Plz help

Here is the HTML code:

```
Price: <span id="totalCost"></span><input type="hidden" name="totalCost">
```

Here is some Javascript:

```
var totalCostEl = document.querySelector('#totalCost');


function calculateTotal() {

  var unitCost = product_price[productEl.value];
  var additionalCost = size_price[sizeEl.value] || 0;
  var qty = quantityEl.value || 0;


  totalCostEl.textContent = `Total cost: $${(unitCost + additionalCost) * qty}`;

}
```

Here is the php:

```
if (!$con)
{die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error()); }
else
{ echo "Order Succeed!" ;}

$var_Price = $_POST["totalCost"];

$sql="INSERT INTO label (product, quantity, size, base, scents, ingredients, packaging, name, email, phone, message, totalCost)
VALUES('$var_Product','$var_Quantity','$var_Size','$var_Base','$var_Scent','$var_Ingredients','$var_Packaging','$var_Name','$var_Email','$var_Phone','$var_Message','$var_Price')";
```

Here is the database:

```
+----+------------+------------------------+------------+---------+-----------+----------+-------------------+---------------+------------+------------------------+----------------+-----------+
| id | name       | email                  | phone      | message | product   | quantity | size              | base          | scents     | ingredients            | packaging      | totalCost |
+----+------------+------------------------+------------+---------+-----------+----------+-------------------+---------------+------------+------------------------+----------------+-----------+
| 22 | xxx        | xxx                    | xxx        |   None  | Face Soap |        1 | Regular Size(3oz) | Dry Skin      | Clove      | Shea Butter            | Co-Brand Label | 0         |
```

I'm able to show the total cost on the website, but I can't insert the total cost to the database. Everything else from the label table was inserted successfully into the database. How to insert the totalCost javascript into the database.

Comment: A `<span>` is not a form control and has no `name` property so this is really confusing how you are trying to POST this to get it to `$_POST["totalCost"];`

Comment: I guess that's why I couldn't insert the total cost into the database, do you know how can fix this?

Comment: By using a form control...input, textarea etc

Comment: Thanks, I'll try

Comment: Hey charlietfl, I want the javascript I build for calculating price shows on the website. If I use input or textarea instead of span, the price will not show. Is there any other way to fix it.

Comment: Remember to assign to `.value` instead of `innerHTML` when it's a form control.

Comment: You probably want to do both; update the span with javascript like you are doing, but also update the form field which can then be submitted somehow to php (it is still a bit unclear how you want to achieve that).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. If I update another form field. Which form should I use?

Comment: You are basically trying to submit a form field that has its value computed by javascript to server side script.  The title of this post is very misleading.

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: Trusting the value submitted to you is a huge mistake. Calculate this server-side. **Never** trust the client.

Comment: After clients choose the product and quantity, prices will automatically show on the webpage. I just want the PHP to insert prices into the database. Clients can't submit any value.

Comment: I'm new to this. I will read the links you provided to me. Thanks

Comment: I flagged this because of the post title, but I think the post title has been corrected. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful to show us the entire `<form>` code but to me it seems like the problem is that you are not setting a value into the hidden input field for the total price.

In you JS, you are showing the total price by assigning it with `totalCostEl.textContent` but `totalCostEl` only refers to the span element which does not get sent along with the form. What you need to do is to select the hidden input element and put the total price value in there as well so it gets sent to the server. Might be easier to give that hidden field an id too, something like `id="totalPriceInput"` so you can easily reference it in your JS.

So,

`<input type="hidden" name="totalCost">`

needs to be

`<input type="hidden" name="totalCost" id="totalPriceInput">`

and in your jS, you can do something like

`document.getElementById('totalPriceInput').value = "the calculated total price here"`

when a form is submitted, only certain elements that take input from the user gets sent to the server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edit some code in HTML and javascript in my question from your answer, but I don't think my javascript is correct. I'm new to javascript.  Could you show me where to add the code you provide to me in JS?

Comment: it should be fine to place that at the end of `calculateTotal`. Also, not that I made a typo in my JS. It should be `getElementById` and not `getElementByID`.

Comment: @Leslie also, it should be `.value` and not `.textContent` for the input field.

Comment: should I do something like this?                                               
  totalCostEl.value = `Total cost: $${(unitCost + additionalCost) * qty}`;
  document.getElementById('totalPriceInput').value = {(unitCost + additionalCost) * qty};
}

Comment: You dont need to use `.value` on `totalCostEl` since it is the span. For the input, you would want to assign the final calculated value. You don't need the curly brackets. Assigning just `(unitCost + additionalCost) * qty` to the input should be fine.

Comment: Glad to help out